# How do I transform an image based on it's features that I've matched with another image?

Tags: python, opencv

I have two images. One original img1 and another one that's the same image but squeezed img2.
I've extracted and matched the features between the two using SIFT and FLANN matcher. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE2un.png.
I've also found the Homography based on the matched features from the following code.

```
src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
```

So my question is, how do I use that Homography to transform the img2 to img1, or as close as possible it is to do so?
I used cv2.warpPerspective() but the resulting image is quite weird.

```
 img2_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, M, img1.shape)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilHYm.png

What should I do?